# Calendar repeating events by date won't work

Tags: android, mobile, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

When recurring events are added by date, they don't appear on the android app. Here's an example App Script that demonstrates the problem:

```
function myFunction() {

  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEventSeries('Dates Repeated',
    new Date('October 7, 2018 03:00:00 PM EST'),
    new Date('October 7, 2018 04:00:00 PM EST'),
    CalendarApp.newRecurrence()
        .addDate(new Date('October 8, 2018'))
        .addDate(new Date('October 10, 2018'))
        .addDate(new Date('October 11, 2018'))
    );
  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEventSeries('Tue Thu Meeting',
    new Date('October 9, 2018 01:00:00 PM EST'),
    new Date('October 9, 2018 02:00:00 PM EST'),
    CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()
        .onlyOnWeekdays([CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY, CalendarApp.Weekday.THURSDAY])
        .until(new Date('October 19, 2018')));

}
```

There are two events "Dates Repeated" and "Tue Thu Meeting".  After running this script, both events show up on Google Calendar Web.

Google Calendar Web:

- "Dates Repeated" appears on Google Calendar Web on Oct 7, 8, 10, 11 as expected.
- "Tue Thu Meeting" appears on Google Calendar Web on Oct 9, 11, 16, 18 as expected.

Google Calendar Android

- "Dates Repeated" event does not appear anywhere.
- "Tue Thu Meeting" appears as expected.

Versions:

- Google Chrome desktop Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Google Calendar Android version 6.0.2-213980666-release
- Android version 9 on Google Pixel

Comment: How long are you waiting? It's possible your app hasn't synced yet..

Comment: Did a couple manual refreshes and waited 2 hours.

Comment: Is this only for recurring events? or any events?

Comment: I've only seen the problem on event series when using addDate.  Note that "Tue Thu Meeting" is the control for this experiment and works as expected on both platforms.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117644838

Comment: You should rather create a issue under Google calendar or the Google calendar android app.